# iPhone/iPad Built-in Mail App prompts "Apple Internet Accounts needs permission..." once upgraded to iOS14

Tags: ios14, apple-mail

We use Office 365 email. we upgraded iOS14 yesterday and noticed the built-in Mail App ask for password. Once I done the authentication, it prompted me another message as shown in the screen cap [iOS14 Mail app prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtoyA.png). I then logon as Global Admin which allow me approve Consent for my phone [Approve consent with Global Admin logon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdJeS.png). However, we can't do it for other users as most of them are working from home. I checked User Settings on Azure. **[User can consent apps setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkuOG.png)** is set to [Yes]. However, it didn't fix the issue. The workaround now is to ask users to install Outlook app which seemed to work. I done some googling and seemed to be an issue prior to iOS14 for some users. Some users had reported rolling back to iOS 13.7 works. Please let me know if you've found a fix. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the best guide I've been able to find on why it happens and how to resolve.

Basically, you have 3 options:

1. Enable users to enable rights for themselves (BAD!)
2. Modify the URL and navigate there as a domain administrator
3. Allow option for users to request access, then review and approve/reject requests from the administrator console

[Andreas Dieckmann - Apple Internet Accounts - Need admin approval](https://diecknet.de/en/2020/05/10/Apple-Internet-Accounts-Office365/)

[EDIT] Looks like you've tried #1-2. If #3 doesn't work, then try setting up a new account in iOS.